# Create a function with take the first n and last n elements

Tags: function, haskell

I want to create a function that keep the first n as well as the last n elements are, all other elements are dropped.

If there are less than or equal to 2n elements, all elements are kept.

```
dropTake 4 [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ] => [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ]
```

My idea was that:

```
dropTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropTake n [] = []
dropTake n (x:xs) 
    | n > 0 = take n (x:xs) ++ drop (length xs - n) xs
    | n < 0 = error "Vorraussetzung nicht erfüllt"
```

Now the command If there are less than or equal to 2n elements, all elements are kept is missing, but how can I wirte it down?

Comment: Basically, all you've done so far is re-implement `take`. Once you have taken the first `n` elements of the list, you still need to take the *last* `n` elements as well: `dropTake 0 _ = []` is simply wrong. (Note that reaching `0` as a result of recursion on the front of the list needs to be handled separately from an actual argument of 0.) You might want to "expand" the trivial definition of `take n xs ++ drop (length xs - n) xs` (using whatever definitions of `take` and `drop` you like) to see how you might approach this.

Comment: @chepner I tried whit your tips, but now, he is always cutting the first numbers also out of the list ;(

Comment: Okay, I changed it, my question is now, how can I say that the function work with the command that If there are less than or equal to 2n elements, all elements are kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to simply compare `2*n` with the length of the list, and return the list as-is if appropriate.

```
dropTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropTake n xs | length xs <= 2*n = xs
dropTake n [] = []
dropTake n (x:xs) 
    | n > 0 = take n (x:xs) ++ drop (length xs - n) xs
    | n < 0 = error "Vorraussetzung nicht erfüllt"
```